# Align several nested div's of a div. (center)

Tags: html, css, css-float

Several nested div's inside a container, the contents (nested divs) are not getting center aligned in it's parent.

```
<div id="parent">
  <span id="menu_0" class="d"></span>
  <span id="menu_1" class="d"></span>
  <span id="menu_2" class="d"></span>
</div>

#parent
{
    float: left;
    height:18px;
    width:980px;
    margin-top:55px;
    text-align:center;
    border: solid red 1px;
}
.d 
{
    background:url(../images/d.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;
    height:18px;
    width:28px;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking (since you have no actual questions in your post), but here's what I see: http://jsfiddle.net/senoramor/3MQrA/  (adjusted some CSS to fit the screen).  What do you want it to look like?

Comment: yes this is what I want, but still can't get it to work, can you please help me learn the issue.

Comment: yes, if you remove a, b, c from the contents of the span, it won't work, I've a background to be used inside.

Comment: A `<span>` isn't a block-level item.  You cannot apply width and height styles to it.  You need some content in your span or nothing will show.

Comment: cool, it worked, I used transparent gif inside. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @SenorAmor you should add this as answer ..

Comment: Done. @iPhoneDeveloper if you want to mark it as correct, that'd be swell. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The container is centre aligned but not what's in it. You'll have to align each div within the container using

```
.d {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TtvNc/3/

Answer (score 0):

A `<span>` isn't a block-level item. You cannot apply width and height styles to it. You need some content in your span or nothing will show.